# Shiny text output to update at the end of SQL query

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem that has been discussed in different ways here but apparently not to face my quite simple need.

I have a simple app that makes a call to an SQL database. I use a button to launch the query.
I would simply need a text showing "click on button" to download at the very beginning. 
Once a user clicks on the button, I would need this output text to show "Downloading the data, please wait".

Once the query is completed and the data has been fully received, I would need the output text to show "Data downloaded successfully."

I've seen [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184568/r-shiny-how-to-update-a-textoutput-multiple-times-in-an-observer) based off the progress bar but I cannot use it since I'm not going through a data.frame. I query the database and I don't know how long this could take.
I've seen [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40997817/reactive-variables-in-shiny-for-later-calculations) based off reactive values  but the text output in this case should react based on the size of the dataframe (0 rows and button clicked -> still downloading the data; >0 rows and button clicked "data downloaded successfully").

Hence, I'm stuck here.
This is my simple code but that ideally does what I would need.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(actionButton("download_btn", "Download Data")),
  fluidRow(textOutput(outputId = "load_data_status")),
  fluidRow(dataTableOutput("output_table"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  cat("\n output$output_table = \n", output$output_table)

  data <- eventReactive(input$download_btn,{
    output$load_data_status <- renderText({ "Downloading data from Server. Please wait..." })
    # here I actually download the data from a database and this could take several seconds
    df <- data.frame(mtcars)
    output$load_data_status <- renderText({ "Data downloaded succesfully." })
    df
  })

  output$output_table <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Take a look at the [shinybusy](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinybusy) package.

Comment: I'll be honest with you and based on my beginner knowledge it doesn't seem like that package can do what I need, but it's probably more me getting stuck with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option A:

Here is a pretty good solution by Dean Attali: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/busy-indicator

#### Option B:

You can listen to *JavaScript* events to:

1. Change text when the button is clicked
2. Change the text again when the output is rendered

I also added `Sys.sleep()` to simulate some loading time.

#### Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML('
    // 1. Change text to "Downloading..." when button is clicked
    $(document).on("shiny:inputchanged", function(event) {
      if (event.name === "download_btn") {
        $("#download_btn").html("Downloading data from Server. Please wait...");
      }
    });

    //. 2. Change text to "Success" when output table is changed
    $(document).on("shiny:value", function(event) {
      if (event.name === "output_table") {
        $("#download_btn").html("Data downloaded succesfully.");
      }
    });        
  '))),
  fluidRow(actionButton("download_btn", "Download Data")),
  fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("output_table"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- eventReactive(input$download_btn,{
    df <- data.frame(mtcars)
    Sys.sleep(3) # Simulate some loading time

    df
  })

  output$output_table <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help. I was trying your solution and even though I see from your gif the result, when I run it on my end, nothing happens. Do I need to load a specific library in order to be able to see the java script component?

Comment: These are the libraries I usually import: library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(reshape2)
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)
library(abDataHub)
library(plotly)
library(ylrSS)
library(htmlTable)

Comment: you probably need to update your `shiny` package. no other package is needed.

Comment: thing is, I have to use whatever the shared R / shiny version on my company's server. Even though I strongly appreciate your answer, unfortunately I'm still stuck on this issue. Is there a way to create a shiny component that could react to a global variable?

Comment: My bad, I just edited the answer (messed up the js comments before). Please check if it works for you now.

Comment: It does work!!! thank you very much! Honestly, this is of huge help! I wish I could give you 1000 points !!

Comment: No problem, and sorry that I left an error in the first version of my answer.